# How can I force Firefox to center image when I am only viewing an image only?

Tags: firefox

1. Right click on an image
2. Select `View Image`

The image is viewed alone but in the left of the browser.
How can I set Firefox to **center** always and **fit** the image if larger than window?

I saw some similar Greasemonkey scripts but I don't know If this can apply on that special view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ImageTweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/imagetweak/) plugin. It will center images for you.

Comment: This does the job but I want to be able to drag the images to the search bar... how can I?

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom in or out of an image by pressing (control) and (+) or (-) keys together, or pressing (control) while turning the wheel on your mouse. I know it's not quite what you asked, but maybe it helps.